# Kotlin JPA issue with open qualifier on entity class

Tags: kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have read that `open` qualifier is required on JPA Entity. Below is my code. I'm using `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:3.0.4`

```
@Entity
open class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    open val id: Long? = null
}


@Repository
interface TestRepository: JpaRepository<Test, Long> {
}


@Component
class Service(private val testRepository: TestRepository){

    @PostConstruct
    fun init() {
         val data = testRepository.getReferenceById(1)
         data.getId()
    }
}
```

But I'm getting error `Hibernate could not initialize proxy – no Session`. Adding `@Transactional` to the class and method does not work. Only 2 ways I found can resolve this error.

1 is remove `open` from `Test` class, so it will become

```
@Entity
class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long? = null
}
```

2 is to set `enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true`

I'm trying to understand why this is against the recommendation. Why `open` qualifier cause such error?

**More details**

Here is the plugins section in my pom.xml

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>19</jvmTarget>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-Xjsr305=strict</arg>
                    </args>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>spring</plugin>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Here is the error trace (masked all sensitive info)

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy [xxx.jpa.entity.Test#55] - no Session
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor.intercept(ByteBuddyInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.ProxyConfiguration$InterceptorDispatcher.intercept(ProxyConfiguration.java:102)
    at xxx.jpa.entity.Test$HibernateProxy$bI6oMG8J.getId(Unknown Source)
    at xxx.xxx$lambda$0(xxx.kt:43)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.invokeConsumer(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:973)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:684)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:533)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.apply(PartitionAwareFunctionWrapper.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionWrapper.apply(FunctionConfiguration.java:785)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration$FunctionToDestinationBinder$1.handleMessageInternal(FunctionConfiguration.java:621)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.doHandleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:105)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace from your logs.

Are you using the Kotlin Spring Boot plugin ?

Comment: I added the plugins section and the error trace. Removing the allopen plugin doesn't do anything to the issue